# Compatibility of Build agents when upgrading from TFS 2010 RTM to TFS 2010 SP1 with Cumulative Update 1

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have TFS 2010 RTM installed on my production server and on all my build agents.  (Meaning I have what was initially released as TFS 2010, no service packs or updates.)

I would like to upgrade my server to the latest TFS 2010 SP1 with the Cumulative Update 1.

To get there I first have to install TFS 2010 SP1 on my prod server.  I then have to install TFS 2010 Cumulative Update 1.

Here is my Question:

If I install TFS 2010 SP1 on my prod server and then install TFS 2010 Cumulative Update 1, are all my build agents going to stop being able to talk to my server?  If so, will they stop working right when I install TFS 2010 SP1?

Basically, I am wondering if I need a multi computer down time.  I would like to just update my Prod Server then go back and update the build agents later (if needed).

**What is the compatibility levels between Build Agents running TFS 2010 RTM and a Server running TFS 2010 SP1 with Cumulative Update 1?**

Comment: You are aware RC is release candidate? No service pack for that. Install RTM first.

Comment: @TomTom - My bad. I meant RTM.  I have updated my question.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SP1 agents can talk to an RTM build controller just fine.  You definitely want to upgrade your agents to SP1 as soon as possible (lots of good fixes), but it won't break the agent communication to upgrade the controller first.